# Meine Freunde oder meine Freundinnen?

Tags: gender

Imagine you have 2 female and 3 male friends and you want to refer to all of them!

For example, you want to say: I love all my friends (all 5).
How do you say such a thing in German?

Ich liebe alle meine(r) *Freunde*.

oder

Ich liebe alle meine(r) *Freundinnen*.

A bit confusing!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Either you use the traditional generic masculine, so simply

> Ich liebe alle meine Freunde

or you make it explicit that it is a mixed group

> Ich liebe alle meine Freundinnen und Freunde

Or choose another more inclusive version like Freund*innen... depending on your audience, they may mind it or not, and if they care, they might hate you for it or appreciate your consideration.

Comment: Why is "Freund*innen" more inclusive than "Freundinnen und Freunde"? Doesn't it exclude non-binary, undecided, people?

Comment: @bakunin allegedly 'Freund*innen' includes any person which does not identify as either, so more the spectrum than just female or male, indicated by the star. But I wouldn't know, but I can respect that

Comment: -1 for suggesting the use of wrong and therefore bad grammar. It should never be taught and never practiced by anyone caring about the correctness of their German.

Comment: @EagleFliesBanana: *»-1 for suggesting the use of wrong and therefore bad grammar.«* In exactly which part of his answer does planetmaker suggest the use of wrong and therefore bad grammar?

Comment: @bakunin: The star is used for very obvious reasons only as an abbreviation in written German. In "normal" (i.e. spoken) German yo say either *»alle meine Freunde«* or *»alle meine Freundinnen und Freunde«*. The star in _»Freund*innen«_ is a variation of the slash in _»Freund/innen«_ which is just a shorthand form for the spoken *»Freunde und Freundinnen«.* So, the pronunciation of _»Freund/innen«_ (and also of _»Freund*innen«_) is *»Freunde und Freundinnen«* or *»Freundinnen und Freunde«.* The novelty of the ...

Comment: ... star, compared to the slash ist, that by using the star, you explicitely also include non-binary genders (like intersexual people for example), while the slash just means men and women, excluding intersexual people and other people with non-binary gender. But is is a quite new convention that is topic of a very emotional political debate. Unfortunately, the debate is often conducted with a lot of hatred, so that rational arguments are hardly heard.

Comment: How the "star [sic! it is an asterisk] [...]explicitely include[s] non-binary genders" eludes me. Especially when you said before that "the pronounciation of 'Freund*innen' is 'Freundinnen und Freunde'. What now?? If it is "Freundinnen und Freunde" then 53 genders Facebook knows are obviously reduced to 2 (feminine and masculine). If this would be a "more inclusive" form it would have to be spoken as "meine Freundinnen, Freunde, befreundeten Transgender-, Tertiär-, Non-binär-, Heute-sich-nicht-so-richtig-maskulin-fühlenden-, Unentschiedenen-, ..... -personen und -personinnen", yes?

Comment: ... Not to forget "Person" is feminine and hence we need a masculine, trans-gender, non-binary, undetermined, etc. ending to reflect that, no? And if we have "Arzt" for male physicians and "Ärztin" for female physicians, then what do we call a non-binary physician? "Arztun"? The asterisk isn't cutting it.

Answer (score 9):

Since in German the generic masculine is used, you can say "Ich liebe alle meine Freunde".

Answer (score 2):

You could go with

> "Ich liebe meinen ganzen Freundeskreis",

in that way navigating around gendrification awkwardness.

Comment: An interesting suggestion! The more overgeneralization, the better!